# Python function: Iterate through a list and add each occurence of the content from the list into a dictionary

Tags: python

I am just doing a practice question from a python textbook by Al Sweigart, and I am stuck figuring out why I could not iterate through a list and then add each item from the list into a dictionary item.

I am using a function called add_inv to manipulate a list and an existing dictionary item by adding the content of the list into the dictionary. Everytime I iterate through the list using a for loop, only the first item in the list get processed by the function. The rest of the items in the list are ignored by the add_inv function - I tested that with the print(list_item) command inside the add_inv function:

#add_inv python function:

```
def add_inv(inven,loot):
    inven = dict(inven)
    for list_item in loot:
        print(list_item)
        inven.setdefault(list_item, 0)
        inven[list_item] = inven[list_item] + 1
        return inven     



treasure = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby' ]
treasure_inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
print(add_inv(treasure_inv, treasure))
```

#output of print add_inv function using the arguments, treasure_inv and treasure:

Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > 

gold coin

{'gold coin': 43, 'rope': 1}

> > > 

Comment: "The rest of the items in the list are ignored by the add_inv function" -- because you told it to ignore them. You are returning in the first iteration of the loop. The return shouldn't be that indented.

Comment: You have a return inside the for loop which causes processing of only the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `return` as soon as you have added a single item from your loot, thus not allowing you to iterate over list `loot`.

This should do the trick:

```
def add_inv(inven, loot):
    inven = dict(inven)
    for list_item in loot:
        inven.setdefault(list_item, 0)
        inven[list_item] = inven[list_item] + 1

    return inven


treasure = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
treasure_inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
print(add_inv(treasure_inv, treasure))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I should have returned the "inven" dictionary outside of the iteration. Thank you very much, jån. That is the perfect answer.

Comment: Exactly, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
def add_inv(inven,loot):
    inven = dict(inven)
    for list_item in loot:
        if list_item not in inven:
            inven[list_item] = 1
        else:
            inven[list_item] += 1
    return inven

treasure = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby' ]
treasure_inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
print(add_inv(treasure_inv, treasure))

#{'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, pakpe. That works perfectly. This is the alternative option of using the "if" statement populate dictionary instead of the "setdefault" method. it looks like the "setdefault" method doesn't like the "for" loop iteration.

Comment: jån has explained what the issue was. I should have returned the "inven" dictionary outside of the iteration. Thank you very much papke, I like your "if" statement option too.